# How do you get "react-scripts test" to work with AWS CodePipeline?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, react-scripts

I have a React app that I generated using Create React App. I'd like to make sure the tests pass before the build starts in AWS CodePipeline. Here is my `buildspec.yml` file which works just fine without the `npm test` command. Once I add the test command, it runs the tests, which I have setup to fail, and then the build just hangs.

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - cd react/menu && npm install
  build:
    commands:
      - npm test
      - npm run-script build

artifacts:
  files: "**/*"
  base-directory: "react/menu/build"
```

Comment: Please add the relevant CodeBuild Build Logs to the OP. In the console, `CodeBuild > Build projects > my-project > [select a build run from the Build history] > [Build Logs tab]`.

Comment: Add the build logs for more information. And make sure to set `CI=true` with `npm test` command so `react-scripts` don't execute tests in watch mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by turning off watch mode as @haseeb-anwar suggested.

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - cd react/menu && npm install
  build:
    commands:
      - npm test -- --watchAll=false
      - npm run-script build

artifacts:
  files: "**/*"
  base-directory: "react/menu/build"
```